# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Cannot read property 'map' of undefined i don't know how to solve i am new to react please help me for this code

```
  {rooms && rooms.length === 0 ? (
          <div className='alert alert-danger'>
            <b>No Rooms</b>
          </div>
        ) : (
          rooms.map((room) => <RoomItem key={room._id} room={room} />)
        )}
```

Comment: Try ```rooms?.map```, because ```rooms``` isn't an array when rendered for the first time, that's my guess..

Answer (score 1):

Let's reverse that logic.

If rooms is defined and it's length is greater than 0, then render rooms.

Else, render "No Rooms"

```js
{
  rooms?.length > 0 ? (
    rooms.map((room) => <RoomItem key={room._id} room={room} />)
  ) : (
    <div className="alert alert-danger">
      <b>No Rooms</b>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add first:
{if(! rooms) return}

Answer (score -1):

Break the code down to its basics and you have:

```js
if (rooms && rooms.length === 0)
  return "No Rooms";
else
  return rooms.map(room => room.id);
```

When `rooms` is `undefined`, `&&` short-circuits (i.e., the second operand is skipped if first is falsey), the code is now equivalent to:

```js
if (undefined) ​return "No Rooms"
else return undefined.map(/*...*/)
```

This is why you're getting the "cannot read property map of undefined" error. I suspect you just added `rooms&&` as you were getting "cannot read property length of undefined" initially. You should try to always put the 'backup case' in the else-block to avoid this issue.

Fix it by reversing the check:

```js
rooms && rooms.length > 0 ? (
 // rooms.map ...
) : (
 // No Rooms ...
)
```